# AngularJS chaining promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatable

I have what I believe should be a simple promise chain in Angular, except for some reason it seems to be executing the second part of the chain before the first part.

```
Client.query( (clients) ->
    $scope.clients = clients
    $scope.loaded = true
).$promise.then( -> 
    $('#table_id').DataTable()
)
```

This is a page that is supposed to load data from the Client resource, and after successful completion bind the return to $scope.clients.  Once that has occurred I want to execute the jQuery DataTable API on the rendered table.

Unfortunately, it seems that when the DataTable function is called nothing has been rendered to the view yet and DataTables replaces the Angular data with a stock "No data available in table" message:

```
Client Name Last Modified
data available in table
Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries
```

I'm sure what I need to do is something really simple but I can't seem to figure it out. Anyone know what I need to do to get DataTables to render correctly?

Comment: You shouldn't ever access or modify the DOM outside of a directive in angular, it will cause all sorts of problems one of which you're currently experiencing.  Check if DataTables already has a directive written for it, most popular jQuery plugins have some previous work by others using Angular already.

Comment: I've tried using angular-datatables (http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables) but I can't get it to return anything other than a console error. I figured this was a simple enough implementation of datatables that it wouldn't be an issue.